# Error code with MATLAB when try to take plots from openfast program

Tags: matlab

I'm new using matlab with OpenFast free Source Software)... Once the matlab mesh has been compiled and the program is compiled with Visual Studio, I plan to use matlab and simulink and it works correctly, but when I try to use the MatlabToolbox (tools) to extract the graphs of the results I get the following error.

OpenFAST

Copyright (C) 2023 National Renewable Energy Laboratory
Copyright (C) 2023 Envision Energy USA LTD

This program is licensed under Apache License Version 2.0 and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
See the "LICENSE" file distributed with this software for details.

OpenFAST-v3.4.0
Compile Info:

- Compiler: Intel(R) Fortran Compiler 2021
- Architecture: 64 bit
- Precision: single
- OpenMP: No
- Date: Jan 13 2023
- Time: 13:46:05
  Execution Info:
- Date: 04/17/2023
- Time: 19:15:54+0200

OpenFAST input file heading:
FAST Certification Test #01: AWT-27CR2 with many DOFs with fixed yaw error and steady wind

Running ElastoDyn.
Nodal outputs section of ElastoDyn input file not found or improperly formatted.
Running AeroDyn14.
WARNING:   AeroDyn 14 is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Running InflowWind.
Running ServoDyn.

FAST_InitializeAll:SrvD_Init:ValidatePrimaryData:Yaw angle and rate are not commanded from
Simulink model.
ValidatePrimaryData:Pitch angles are not commanded from Simulink model.
ValidatePrimaryData:Generator torque and power are not commanded from Simulink model.
ValidatePrimaryData:HSS brake is not commanded from Simulink model.
ValidatePrimaryData:Airfoil control is not commanded from Simulink model.
ValidatePrimaryData:Cable control is not commanded from Simulink model.

Time: 0 of 20 seconds.

Time: 2 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 4 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 6 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:60.

Time: 8 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 10 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 12 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 14 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 16 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 18 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

Time: 20 of 20 seconds.  Estimated final completion at 19:15:59.

OpenFAST completed.

Reading from the file ../../../reg_tests/r-test/glue-codes/openfast/AWT_YFix_WSt/AWT_YFix_WSt.SFunc.out with heading:
"Description from the FAST input file: FAST Certification Test #01: AWT-27CR2 with many DOFs with fixed yaw error and steady wind".
**ReadFASTtext::Error -1 reading from file, "../../../reg_tests/r-test/glue-codes/openfast/AWT_YFix_WSt/windows-intel/AWT_YFix_WSt.out"**
Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds.

Error in PlotFASToutput (line 175)
outData{iFile,1} = data{iFile}(:,TimeIndex);

Error in Run_Test01_SIG (line 39)
PlotFASToutput({[ OpenFASTRoot 'AWT_YFix_WSt.SFunc.out'],[ OpenFASTRoot 'windows-intel/AWT_YFix_WSt.out']},{'SFunc','exe'});

> > 

I need to extract graphs from the Outputs to compare differents simulations.